# What are the 'P' values in some cipher string?

Tags: tls, hash, cipher-selection, ciphers

Most of the cipher strings I see are in the format:

```
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
```

However, I've come across workstations with cipher strings that have an additional 'P' value:

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P521
```

What are the 'P' values for (what do they represent)? Also, some look like common hashing lengths, but the '521' above is not a typo.

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, I should have asked my questions more specifically:
1. What is the difference between cipher suites with and without the P-values?
2. Are cipher strings with P-values stronger or weaker?
3. In basic terms, what does the addition of P-values do for the PKI process? Is it a nested/additional message authentication of some sort?
4. Is 521 a hash length? If not, what is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### P521 is an elliptic curve

“P521” is a dead giveaway for an [elliptic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve) which SECG and TLS formally call [secp521r1](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-8) and which [NIST FIPS 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/fips/nist.fips.186-4.pdf) calls P-521. An elliptic curve is a mathematical domain used by elliptic curve algorithm such as ECDH and ECDSA.

Curves are generally known by a name that includes some information about the type of curve and the key size¹. The letters “sec” stand for [SECG](http://www.secg.org/) (Standards for Efficient Cryptography Group), and the specifically for the curves described in [SEC2](http://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf). The following P is because the curve is over a prime field (a [finite field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) whose number of elements is prime). 521 is the bit size associated with the curve. The R indicates that certain parameters of the curve were generated at random, and the final 1 is because this is the first (and so far only) secp521r curve.

Curve parameters are typically chosen in such a way as to make calculations faster, given mathematical constraints to ensure that the parameters have the required security properties. In particular, it helps if the size of the field differs from a power of 2 by as few bits as possible, because that allows fast [modulo reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). It happens that 2<sup>521</sup>-1 is prime. There's no prime that's nearly as nice and has 512 bits or a little less.

In terms of [sizes](https://www.keylength.com/en/compare/), today, 256 bits is considered enough for elliptic curves for ephemeral key exchange (ECDH) and signature (ECDSA). As usual, larger sizes give more resistance (but being more resistant that “unbreakable in practice” isn't a practical benefit) at the cost of less performance.

#### Elliptic curves and TLS cipher suites

A TLS [cipher suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher_suite) is a set of parameters that describe how the TLS protocol sets up the keys that are used for the communication. See [How does SSL/TLS work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work/20847#20847) for more information. For example, `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256` means to perform a key exchange using elliptic-curve Diffie-Hellman (ECDH) with single-use (E for ephemeral keys), verifying the server's signature with RSA, and using AES-128-CBC to encrypt the secure channel and HMAC-SHA-256 to authenticate it. The client and the server negotiate which cipher suite to use at the beginning of the TLS connection (the client sends the list of cipher suites that it supports, and the server picks one and lets the client know which one). The choice of elliptic curve for ECDH is not part of the [cipher suite encoding](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-4). The curve is negotiated separately (here too, the client proposes and the server decides).

`TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P521` is not a thing that's different from `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256`. It means to use `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256` with secp521r1 for the ECDHE part.

Most TLS server software allows the administrator to configure which security parameters it's willing to support. Sometimes this is done independently for each piece (which key exchange types, which key agreement algorithms, which hashes for signature, which elliptic curves, which hashes for HMAC, which symmetric ciphers, which AEAD algorithms, …). Here you select which elliptic curve to support separately for each cipher suite. The choice of which parameters to configure together is a matter of convenience vs flexibility.

¹  <sub>More precisely, it's the size in bits of the coordinates of points on the curve. But for all common curves, that's also the size in bits of the private key.</sub>

Comment: A Windows specific footnote: It's also worth noting that the elliptic curve specifiers _Pxxx are no longer required in Windows 10/Server 2016 but they are required in 2012R2/Win8.1 and earlier... this is important if you are modifying the cipher suites, e.g. with Group Policy on your clients or servers -- you can't just use the exact same cipher suite strings on both new and old OSes.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest that these mean the curve used within the ECDHE key exchange, i.e. NIST P-256, NIST P-384 and NIST P-521. These are not actually part of the cipher itself (i.e. the 16-bit cipher id used in the TLS handshake) but it looks like Microsoft has added it to their cipher syntax.

There's really no difference between cipher suites with and without the "P value", except that one is being explicit about which elliptic curve it's using, while the other will use a system default.

Comment: Edited to directly answer the question. Hope that's ok.

Comment: Thank you for your edits. Unfortunately, Gilles answered in a way that made everything very clear, so I had to give him the checkmark. You've got the most upvotes though! +1 from me. Your last paragraph was also an important point to be explicit about for me; definitely helpful. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

They are the naming for [NIST ECC Curves](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-56Ar3.pdf). Also see at [NIST.FIPS.186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf)

```
NIST  RFC 4492

P-256 secp256r1  
P-384 secp384r1 
P-521 secp521r1
```